# How to insert combo box value into Access using C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, combobox, oledb

I cannot enter combo box values to the database it says insert query cannot contain multi values and gives the error on the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery. Help me to solve this problem. Im just a rookie in c#

[2 text box and 2 combo box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiKKA.png)
[2 combo box values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DTMN.png)

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:/Films/Database/Films/FilmDB/FilmsDB.accdb");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Films(DVD_No,Films_1,Category_1,SubCategory_1)VALUES(@no,@f1,@cat1,@scat1)";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("no", TextBox1.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("f1", TextBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cat1", ComboBox1.GetItemText(ComboBox1.SelectedItem));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("scat1", ComboBox2.GetItemText(ComboBox1.SelectedItem));

            //open con
            conn.Open();
            //exec cmd
            int row = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (row == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Stored in the Database");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
            //close con
            conn.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception c)
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Record failed" + c.Message);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN - OleDbCommand.CommandText Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.commandtext(v=vs.110).aspx):

The OLE DB.NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL Statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter.

Replace your CommandText with the following:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Films(DVD_No,Films_1,Category_1,SubCategory_1)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
```

You've already added the parameters in the proper order. Good luck!

Comment: Im much appreciated for the help. I have used what you said but the error comes from the combo box.